# selecting options shows different content, how should i tackle this?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

This has to be a duplicate, but i can't find the right anwser for my problem. So i want the selected options, generate different forms from data they get out of the database. I already have the database connection, I'm just alittle confused on how to do the dynamic generation in jsp.

[image: dropdown menu]

[image: The generated code]

So the red one is the dropdown menu, and the selected option should generate the green box. The question i'm asking is should I go full javascript? I've read that jsp shouldn't be mixed with javascript. Since i don't see a posible way to do that in jsp alone. (I don't need the code, just how to tackle this, still learning)

Comment: You can't do this dynamically with jsp until it is server side. You should go pure js.

Comment: As a messy suggestion you may load all possible forms and just play with visibility of forms so you no more need to connect to database.

Comment: How to go about getting the information for the selected option out of the database to the javascript function. Or get every single one and then just send the correct one?